# JavaScript - Trying to find direction based on distance

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a simple treasure hunt game using input boxes that act as both input fields and game display. The game has a hero - h and multiple killers - k, controlled by the computer, that try to kill the hero.

Here is an example board that I have:

[image: example board]

So far I have hard coded some if statements to check the coordinates of the hero and a given killer (based on the input box that they are currently in) to figure out which way the killer should move (up,down,right,left and diagonally). However, it does not always find the best direction to go for.

```
if (killerX < heroX) {
  if (killerY < heroY) {
    console.log("move down andright");
  } else if (killerY > heroY) {
    console.log("move up and right");
  }
}
```

I was thinking about using Dijkstra's algorithm but I do not know how to implement it for my given problem. I am looking for a more efficient alternative for finding which way the killer has to move in order to get closer to the hero.

Comment: 'However, it does not always find the best direction to go for.' could you clarify what is different between your expected direction and the direction given by your snippet?

Comment: I actually use the same logic in an old game I'm (stopped) developing (with some help). Check out my [`io-functions`](https://github.com/RUJodan/SourceUndead/blob/master/routes/io-functions.js), it calculates distance based on coordinate bearing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like:

```
function getMove(killerX, killerY, heroX, heroY) {
    let move = [];
    if (killerY < heroY) {
        move.push("up");
    } else if (killerY > heroY) {
        move.push("down");
    }
    if (killerX < heroX) {
        move.push("left");
    } else if (killerX > heroX) {
        move.push("right");
    }
    if (move.length) {
        return "move " + move.join(" and ");
    }
    return "you've got them!";
}
```

The reason for the array is that you may not always need to move both vertically and horizontally.

In that, I've assumed that toward zero is "up" and "left" (which doesn't quite match your question, but I think your text is just an example).

Live Example with tests:

```js
function getMove(killerX, killerY, heroX, heroY) {
    let move = [];
    if (killerY < heroY) {
        move.push("up");
    } else if (killerY > heroY) {
        move.push("down");
    }
    if (killerX < heroX) {
        move.push("left");
    } else if (killerX > heroX) {
        move.push("right");
    }
    if (move.length) {
        return "move " + move.join(" and ");
    }
    return "you've got them!";
}
function test(killerX, killerY, heroX, heroY, expect) {
    let move = getMove(killerX, killerY, heroX, heroY);
    console.log(`(${killerX}, ${killerY}), {${heroX}, ${heroY}): ${move} <== ${move === expect ? "OK" : "ERROR, should be: " + expect}`);
}
test(3, 3, 3, 4, "move up");
test(3, 3, 1, 4, "move up and right");
test(3, 3, 1, 3, "move right");
test(3, 3, 1, 1, "move down and right");
test(3, 3, 3, 1, "move down");
test(3, 3, 4, 1, "move down and left");
test(3, 3, 4, 3, "move left");
test(3, 3, 4, 4, "move up and left");
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: That works perfectly and is a lot cleaner that my implementation which contains a lot of IFs. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have any wall on your map it is a very trivial exercice !

There is 2 problems in your code. Firstly you do not handle the case `killerX > heroX` and secondly you have to move step by step, not 2 step by 2 step.

```
let diffX = killerX - playerX;
let diffY = killerY - playerY;

if(Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
  if(diffX>0) {
    console.log('move left');
  }
  else {
    console.log('move right');
  }
} else {
  if(diffY>0) {
    console.log('move up');
  } else {
    console.log('move down');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not resist to write a Dijkstra implementation for this. This is quite possibly over-sized for your problem.

```js
/**
 * Set up and return the game board, which is an array with one object per field on the board
 */
function buildBoard(sizeX, sizeY) {
    const board = [];

    for (let y = 0; y < sizeY; y++) {
        for (let x = 0; x < sizeX; x++) {
            const field = {x, y, distance: Number.MAX_VALUE, weight: 1, predecessor: null};
            board.push(field);
        }
    }

    return board;
}

/**
 * Run Dijkstra to find the closest path on the playing field from point a to point b
 */
function getPathOnBoardFromAToB(board, a, b) {
    const fieldAtA = board.find(node => node.x === a.x && node.y === a.y);
    const fieldAtB = board.find(node => node.x === b.x && node.y === b.y);

    fieldAtA.distance = 0;

    const unvisitedFields = [...board];

    while (unvisitedFields.length > 0) {
        const currentField = unvisitedFields.sort((n1, n2) => n1.distance > n2.distance ? 1 : -1)[0];
        unvisitedFields.splice(unvisitedFields.indexOf(currentField), 1);

        // all fields that are up to 1 field away in both X and Y directions are neighors that can be visited from
        // the current field
        const neighbors = unvisitedFields.filter(field => Math.abs(field.x - currentField.x) <= 1 && Math.abs(field.y - currentField.y) <= 1);

        // see if any of the neighbors is reachable more easily via the current field than before
        for (const neighbor of neighbors) {
            const distanceViaCurrentField = currentField.distance + neighbor.weight;
            if (distanceViaCurrentField < neighbor.distance) {
                // relax
                neighbor.distance = distanceViaCurrentField;
                neighbor.predecessor = currentField;
            }
        }

    }

    return buildPathViaPredecessors(fieldAtB);
}

/**
 * Called with the target field once Dijkstra has run, generates an array that contains the field-by-field
 * path from the predecessors set
 */
function buildPathViaPredecessors(targetField) {
    let currentField = targetField;
    const path = [];
    while (currentField != null) {
        path.push(currentField);
        currentField = currentField.predecessor;
    }
    return path;
}

function renderPath(path) {
    console.log(path.reverse().map(field => `[ ${field.x}, ${field.y} ]`).join(' -> '));
}

const killer = {x: 8, y: 7};
const hero = {x: 0, y: 2};

const board = buildBoard(10, 10);
const bestWay = getPathOnBoardFromAToB(board, killer, hero);

renderPath(bestWay);
```